# "Nothing to commit, working directory clean" message when trying to commit

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to follow a tutorial to create a blogging website (http://tutorials.jumpstartlab.com/projects/blogger.html), but while following the steps I'm running into some errors. I've created an empty repository https://github.com/khpeek/jumpstart-blogger and would like push the code from the `~/blogger` directory to it. I've tried the following commands:

```bash
kurt@kurt-ThinkPad:~/blogger$ git init
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /home/kurt/blogger/.git/
kurt@kurt-ThinkPad:~/blogger$ git add .
kurt@kurt-ThinkPad:~/blogger$ git commit -m "first blogger commit"
On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
kurt@kurt-ThinkPad:~/blogger$ git remote add origin git@github.com:khpeek/jumpstart-blogger.git
fatal: remote origin already exists.
```

What firstly puzzles me is the "working directory clean" warning, as there is content in the directory:

```bash
kurt@kurt-ThinkPad:~/blogger$ ls
app  config     db       Gemfile.lock  log     Rakefile     test  vendor
bin  config.ru  Gemfile  lib           public  README.rdoc  tmp
```

Can anyone shed light on why I get the "working directory clean" error? (And perhaps also on the subsequent "fatal: remote origin already exists" error)?

P.S. I understand that the .gitignore file could be of importance here. Its contents are as follows:

```bash
# See https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files for more about ignoring files.
#
# If you find yourself ignoring temporary files generated by your text editor
# or operating system, you probably want to add a global ignore instead:
#   git config --global core.excludesfile '~/.gitignore_global'

# Ignore bundler config.
/.bundle

# Ignore the default SQLite database.
/db/*.sqlite3
/db/*.sqlite3-journal

# Ignore all logfiles and tempfiles.
/log/*
!/log/.keep
/tmp
```

Comment: `Reinitialized existing Git repository` + `fatal: remote origin already exists` - didn't you start your project by cloning a repo ? You may already have done the setup and commits (or at least it was done by cloning the repo).

Comment: Did you run `git status`, and what does it tell you?

Comment: `git status` returns the same message: `On branch master - nothing to commit, working directory clean`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try cloning the repo you created on Github by executing this in your working directory:

```
git clone https://github.com/khpeek/jumpstart-blogger.git
```

Then run this:

```
git status
```

See, if your files are there and not added yet, then run:

```
git add .
git commit -m "First Commit"
```

Finally, check git status again!

Hope I helped...

Answer (score 6):

I just 'started over' by removing the .git directory,

```
rm -rf .git
```

and re-running the commands. This worked (I still had to [add an SSH key for my GitHub account](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account/#platform-linux) for the last step), although I'm not sure why it wasn't working previously.

Comment: The reason this worked is because you already had a repository setup with all those files in it. If you'd created a new file or modified one, then `git add .` would have added those changes and then the commit would work. As it was git had nothing to add, so no commit to be made.